# How do I scale a flexbox element with min and max width?

Tags: html, css

I wish to display three boxes next to each other in a flexbox. The outer boxes are blue and the inner box is red. The red box has a min-width of 228px, a max-width of 362px, and a width of 100%. What I would like is for only the red box to be displayed when the width of the window is 362px or less (the blue boxes are invisible). Only after the width is greater than 362px would I like the blue boxes to expand equally so that the red box remains with a fixed width of 362px in the middle.

I have attached a sample I believed should work but I observe that the blue boxes and the red box both grow proportionally until the red box is 362px at which point only the blue boxes expand.

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; flex-flow: row nowrap;">
  <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%; background-color: blue;
          flex-basis: auto; flex-grow: 0;"></div>
  <div style="height: 80px; min-width: 228px; max-width: 362px; width: 100%;
          background-color: red; flex-basis: auto; flex-grow: 1;"></div>
  <div style="height: 80px; width: 100%; background-color: blue;
          flex-basis: auto; flex-grow: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width:100%` *(the culprit)* from the blue box  and add `flex-grow:1` to them so they expand only when there is space left:

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.red {
  height: 80px;
  min-width: 228px;
  max-width: 362px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not really working as expected. The red box always stays at the width of 362px instead of shrinking with the window, when the window is smaller than 362px. I basically want that box to be responsive for the window size between 228 and 362 (and blue boxes should have the width of 0 at this window size).

Comment: @ShahrzadMasoumnia did you try the code in the snippet here? because the red element should shrink, probably you didn't copy all my code

Comment: When I run the snippet, the size of the red box stays at 362px. I fixed the issue by adding the flex-grow: 1 to the red box as well.

Comment: @ShahrzadMasoumnia sorry but no you don't need flex-grow and if you run the snippet and inspect the element you will see that it will shrink below 362px and will stop at 228px